# Accessing subpatterns in regex with preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, php-5.5

I have the following regex:

`(<div class="dotted-highlight">(.*?)\s*){2,}<ul>`

which is matching the following string:

`<div class="dotted-highlight">The cover letter should include: 
<div class="dotted-highlight"><ul>`

And I need to access `The cover letter should include` so I tried:

```
    <?php
    $textarea = '<div class="dotted-highlight">The cover letter should include: 
<div class="dotted-highlight"><ul>';
    $replacing_to = '(<div class="dotted-highlight">(.*?)\s*){2,}<ul>';
    $replacing_with = '$1<ul>';
    $textarea = preg_replace('#'.$replacing_to.'#', $replacing_with, $textarea);
    ?>
```

`$replacing_with` adds `<div class="dotted-highlight">` instead of the desired text: `The cover letter should include:`

So the output would be:

`<ul>`

and Expected OUTPUT would be:

`The cover letter should include: <ul>`

FIDDLE:

http://codepad.org/j8EnRBFI

REGEX TESTER

http://www.regexr.com/3bkb8

Comment: `strip_tags($textarea, '<ul>')`

Comment: @JonathanKuhn Can't do that string is much larger i only added the point that I want to make, how to match subpattern. in this case.

Comment: Your replacement is going to probably need to use `$2` as it is the second group that is the `(.*?)`.

Comment: doesn't work with $2 either it's a subpatter also tried with $1\1 and it outputted <div class="dotted-highlight">

Comment: $1 is the div, which is the first group. $2 should be the .* which is what you want.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn Have a look http://codepad.org/j8EnRBFI

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87407/discussion-between-adrian-and-jonathan-kuhn).

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like my work recently blocked the chat for SO.

Comment: I see, let me know via comments then.

Comment: Do you consider a DOM parser based solution? The regex does not return the text as it captures one line then another, and only the last one is kept - see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bT6xN2/1). This shows how insecure regexps are when it comes to HTML parsing.

Comment: @stribizhev This is what I wanted to do, the issue is accessing the subpatterns

Comment: Well first thing I see when looking over your pattern is that at best your `(.*?)\s*` will match the first word. That essentially means match everything up to the first space which in the test string would be `The`. Your actual entire pattern is matching both divs, but the group is only matching the second one because the first. If you look here: https://regex101.com/r/sD5bU4/1, The entire match is blue but the first group is green. What are you trying to match on this? Couldn't you just match everything from the first div through the ul and strip tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use this and use the second capture group:

```
((<div class="dotted-highlight">)([^<\n]*)\s?).*?\2.*?<ul>
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/bT6xN2/2)

[3v4l](https://3v4l.org/1iaXT)

Comment: It works, but not as the old one, I added {2,} because the replacement should take place if there are 2 or more patterns, right now if I remove the first <div class="dotted-highlight"> it will match the second one and it should not.

Comment: @Adrian try my updated regular expression. All of the examples have been updated.